# get more metrics with http.server.request metrics using mircrometer and statsd

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, datadog, micrometer

How do I get all the metrics including status codes and exceptions using micrometer and statsd with flavor datadog. I am using maven dependency for micrometer-statsd and spring-boot actuator ?

I have added @Timed annotation according to spring boot actuator configuration to a controller. But in the graphite I only see http.server.requests.max BUT no exceptions or status codes.

Can someone point out what config am I missing ?

```
@RestController
@Timed
@Slf4j
public class AccountsController {

@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@Timed(value = "createAccount.timer", percentiles = {0.9, 0.99}, histogram = true)
@Counted(value = "compass.createAccount.counter")
public AccountResponse createAccount(@RequestBody CreateAccountRequest 
createAccountRequest){
// Business logic
}
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MetricConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public CountedAspect countedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new CountedAspect(registry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample code demonstrating your endpoint and how you are using `@Timed`. Also, consider using the `LoggingMeterRegistry` so you can see in the logs the metrics that are being recorded, that will let you know if you have the metric and it is a Datadog issue

Comment: I have used @Timed Annotation at both class and method levels, I can see metrics for http.server.requests.max but cannot see request response or exception metrics.

Comment: @checketts do you have any suggestions ?